# is $\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}>\frac{1-G(x)}{1-H(x)}$ true if $G(x) > H(x) > x$ on (0,1)?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, auction-theory

In my research there are two CDFs, $G(x)$, $H(x)$ which support is [0,1]. The CDFs are twice differentiable and $G(x) > H(x) > x$ on (0,1). -> stochatical dominance.

My crucial condition is

$\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}>\frac{1-G(x)}{1-H(x)}$

---

My questions is

is $\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}>\frac{1-G(x)}{1-H(x)}$ true if $G(x) > H(x) > x$ on (0,1)?

Comment: I add more questions.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio showed that the statement is in general not true, but he said it may hold if $G(x)$ and $H(x)$ are both concave. So, Is the statement true is $G(x)$ and $H(x)$ are both concave?

Comment: And actually, I have a complicate relationship between $G(x)$ and $H(x)$. $G(x)=H(\beta^{−1}(x))$  where $\beta(x)$=$x−\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1−H(x)}{1−H(z)}dz$. So, In this case, is the statement true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inequalities about functions hardly imply inequalities about their derivatives. If we consider
$$ G(x)=x+\frac{\sin^2(5\pi x)}{5\pi},\qquad H(x)=x+\frac{\sin^2(10\pi x)}{20\pi} $$
then both $G(x)$ and $H(x)$ are non-negative and weakly increasing on $(0,1)$, with $G(x)\geq H(x)\geq x$, but $\frac{G'(x)}{H'(x)}-\frac{1-G(x)}{1-H(x)}$ has a lot of changes of sign over $(0,1)$.

---

On the other hand the inequality $\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}\geq\frac{1-G(x)}{1-H(x)}$ stands some chance to hold if $G(x)> H(x) > x$ on $(0,1)$ and both $G(x)$ and $H(x)$ are concave on $[0,1]$. It appears to be true for the test functions $F(x)=x^{\alpha}(2-x^{\alpha})$ with $\alpha\in(0,1)$, for instance.

Comment: Hi, Jack D'Aurizio. Thank you so much for your answer. First of all, I usually use concave function for $G(x)$ and $H(x)$, so do you have a specific sketch of a proof for a concave function??

Comment: Also, this might go too complicated, but $G(x)$ and $H(x)$ has an intricated relationship in my model. $G(x)=H(\beta^{-1}(x))$ where $\beta(x)$ is $x-\int^{x}_{0}\frac{1-H(x)}{1-H(z)}dz$. Does it help for the assumptions to imply the inequality?

Comment: Anyway, I really appreciate your answer. It is very insightful.

Comment: @JinsooBae: in your model $G$ and $H$ appear to be related via a sort of [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation). Can you provide more informations about the problem you are currently tackling? They might be useful for deriving further (geometric) insights.

Comment: Hi, @Jack D'Aurizio. I added the entire problem that I am tackling as a separate question. Please follow the link. I select your answer for this question. Please look at my original problem and help me. I almost finished one of my paper expect this one important problem....

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680251/how-to-show-that-a-selection-b-1v-is-always-less-than-another-selection-b-2